# HTML Append HREF

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, disqus

What exactly does it mean to append in HTML?

I'm having a situation with my [disqus code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38578176/disqus-code-situation) and i noticed on the tutorial it tells me to do this:

Append #disqus_thread to the href attribute in your links. This will tell Disqus which links to look up and return the comment count. For example: `<a href="http://foo.com/bar.html#disqus_thread">Link</a>`.

I'm not sure exactly what that means. Do i add that to the HOME button link?

Comment: Append simply means to add to the end of. Regarding disqus specifically, I'm not familiar with their API, but it sounds like based on what you have in your question, you append it to whatever link you need the disqus to point to. If you need it on the home button, then yes. Otherwise, just add it where you need it.

Comment: @Jacques Thank you for your response. I understand now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From jQuery append description:

> Description: Insert content, specified by the parameter, to the end of each element in the set of matched elements.

So i think that you are doing it right. Btw, do you have any problem doing that?